# Why was the Avengers movie called something different in the UK?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, title, the-avengers

In the UK the movie is called "[Avengers Assemble](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPoHPNeU9fc)"

Why was it given a different name in that market?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The Avengers was given a somewhat different name because of the British TV show [The Avengers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_%28TV_series%29).  The new name was to help keep them separate and to avoid any confusion for audiences in the UK.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_%282012_film%29#Release) says:

> In February 2012, Disney announced that the film's title would be
>   changed in the United Kingdom to avoid confusion with the British TV
>   series of the same name, as well as its 1998 film adaptation, but this
>   led to confusion over the film's actual title. Empire magazine
>   reported that the film would be titled Marvel Avengers Assemble
>   while The Hollywood Reporter said that it would be called simply
>   Avengers Assemble.

Comment: Probably worth noting that The Avengers isn't a *current* TV show, it last aired in the 80s I think.

Comment: Also interesting that the 1963 Avengers character Cathy Gale would have a leather jump suit http://femformidable.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/year-1962-cathy-gale.html years before Neal Adams re-invented Natasha Romanoff in 1970.

Comment: Movie people seem to have a paranoia about this sort of thing.  Witness *The Secret of NIMH*, where Mrs. Frisby was renamed "Mrs. Brisby" to avoid infringing on the Frisbee(!) trademark.

Comment: It was possibly also a copyright thing?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: There is also a [movie from 1998](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118661/) based on the TV series, also titled *The Avengers.*

Answer (score 13):

They changed the name in UK because of having the same name to TV show [The Avengers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_%28TV_series%29). So they changed the name but only for UK.

They said-

> “Well sir, with people who associate the name ‘The Avengers’ with the
>   TV show, there’s a slim chance that they’ll get confused by the movie
>   poster and so may not want to watch our movie.”

Avengers Assemble name is selected because The Avengers team say it every time they go into battle in comics and its the most common phrase, So that's the whole reason for this.

Comment: However, "Suit up!" appears to be the battle cry most often used in the film.  I have a feeling NPH is behind this.

Comment: @BilltheLizard NPH? Do u mean Neil Patrick Harris?

Comment: Yes, "Suit up!" was his catchphrase on one of the early seasons of *How I Met Your Mother*.

Comment: @BilltheLizard i am not familiar with HIMYM , so its an alien joke for my human mind :)

Comment: Is that actually a quote from someone or did you just make it up?