# How did Thor know about the Chitauri and Lokis plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

When Thor first boards SHIELD's ship in [*The Avengers*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/), he explains about the Chitauri and how they are going to come to win the earth over for Loki.

How did he know about all this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for: [Thor: The Dark World Prelude](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Thor%3a_The_Dark_World_Prelude). It is a comic book set documenting the events after [Thor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800369/), leading up to [The Avengers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/), then bridging the gap to [Thor: The Dark World](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1981115/).

To quote from the Wikipedia article (the first link) describing the comic:

> "...One year [after the events of Thor], with The Realm Eternal still in repair mode.
>   Everyone has pressing concerns about looming conflicts with the
>   Trolls, Marauders, Badoon and Ice Giants and have seemingly forgotten
>   about Loki, having written him off for dead. Except for his mother
>   Frigga who uses her powers to locate her foster-son in Chituari space
>   with Thanos, The Other and their army. It's Frigga who alerts Odin and
>   Thor to Loki's plan regarding the Tesseract..."

So Thor knew about the plan through his mother, who had located her son Loki and understood, given his location, what his plans were.

Comment: So the movie itself doesn't give an answer?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Boo and hiss! You've Americanised The Avengers movie :P It was Avengers Assemble over here in the UK. No the movie itself doesn't given an answer. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if the comic was created specifically because so many people had questions (similarly to the Animatrix being released due to the amount of questions people had about the Matrix to Matrix Reloaded gap).

Comment: Haha, I know and that's a [common source of confusion](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2268/49). ;-)

Comment: Nice link, didn't actually know that was the reason!

Comment: *"didn't actually know that was the reason!"* - Indeed *Marvel*'s title changes are [not always clearly understandable](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13508/49) (but enough with the cross-question references ;-)).