# Why did Netflix rename "What Happened to Monday" to "7 Sisters"

Tags: title, netflix, what-happened-to-monday

The movie [What Happened To Monday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Happened_to_Monday) was released by Netflix on their streaming service, and kept that name for the majority of its stay. Recently, Netfix changed the name to "7 Sisters" but kept the movie poster titled "What Happen To Monday" (reference: Netflix Canada). You can no longer find the movie by the original name when you search for it.

There is no mention of the name change on the [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1536537/) page.

I can find no reference online as to why the name was changed, and if you've watched the film.

Comment: From the trivia section of the IMDB page: *The title changed to "Seven Sisters" during post-production but when Netflix bought the film, it was changed back to "What Happened to Monday", its original title.*

Comment: I must be going blind. I didn't read the pages but just searched for "7 sisters" instead of "seven sisters"

Comment: Also, Netflix UK still lists it as "What happened to Monday?". Also also, I'm curious what plot twist you're talking about. The film's IMDB description says it's about septulplets so it's not really giving anything away by calling it "Seven Sisters" is it?

Comment: @Darren yeah, I should remove that from the question. I thought the sisters were revealed later in the film, but it starts out with their birth. My mind isn't very sharp this morning. sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because film had two names ;

***What Happened to Monday*** in USA , Germany

***Seven Sisters*** in Canada, France, Italy and Slovakia)

From [Also known as section of](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1536537/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ov_inf#akas) of IMDb:

> - (original title): Seven Sisters
> - Brazil: Onde Está Segunda?
> - Canada (alternative title) (English title): 7 Sisters
> - Germany: What Happened to Monday?
> - Greece: Τι συνέβη στη Δευτέρα
> - Hungary: Hét nővér
> - Italy: Seven Sisters
> - Lithuania: Septynios seserys
> - Moldova: Sapte surori
> - Portugal: Sete Irmãs
> - Russia: Тайна 7 сестёр
> - Turkey (Turkish title): Yedinci Hayat
> - Ukraine: Сiм сестер
> - USA: What Happened to Monday
> - World-wide (English title): What Happened to Monday

So it looks like Netflix must have corrected the title to Canadian version. And this is not the first time film having different name in different countries. It has been discussed here few times too:

[Why was the Avengers movie called something different in the UK?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2268/1190)

[Why do many movie titles differ between the U.S. and the UK?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2272/1190)

[Why was the title changed to Dark Kingdom in the German release?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13508/1190)