# Why is Pepper Potts missing from last movies with Iron Man?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe

In *Age Of Ultron*, *Civil War* and probably other movies I missed, Pepper Potts (Gwyneth Paltrow) is missing (though she's still mentioned by characters). Is there a real-world reason for that?

Comment: Didn't she dump him in one of the Iron Man movies?

Comment: I think it's just mentioned, not shown onscreen.

Comment: It's mentioned in *Civil War* that Tony and Pepper are on a break, but this didn't happen in the *Iron Man* movies. They became an item at the end of *Iron Man 2* and were still together at the end of *Iron Man 3*.

Comment: He mentioned her in age of ultron too

Comment: Yes that's the in-plot explaination however I suspect there are real world reasons (like actress asking too much money, or low budget for gaining more income for extra avengers movie.. whatever). The fact they always mention Pepper is maybe a way to convince the actress to act again? (Ex. the Pepper Popps hologram text in Civil War)

Comment: Missing Pepper is a Plothole to me (that's why I suspect there are real world reasons), How can they be on a break plot-wise after Iron Man 3 and without any real explaination apart a short mention?.

Comment: ... None of the girlfriends are ever included in the group movies.

Comment: And Nathalie Portman? I wished she was in the Avengers films too

Comment: @Catija Pepper was in Avengers 1, and Peggy Carter was in Avengers 2 (albeit in a dream-scene).  Jane was mentioned (and her photograph shown) in Avengers 1 as well.

Comment: These are semi-major actresses (ones who have had leading roles) cast as very minor, almost extra-level parts for these Avenger movies.

I'd guess that, unless like in the original Iron Man or Thor where their roles were major, they couldn't afford to pay Paltrow or Portman rates for such minor roles, so they essentially wrote them out.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Gwenyth Paltrow's contract with Marvel Studios ended after *Iron Man 3*.**

From an [article on ComicbookMovie.Com](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/iron_man/gwyneth-paltrow-confirms-that-her-contract-with-marvel-ended-after-iron-a78107);

> While it was widely assumed that Gwyneth Paltrow was another star who had been signed up for a ridiculous number of Marvel movies, she has now told Empire Online that **her contract expired with Iron Man 3**! "My deal is over as well," she revealed when asked whether she think Robert Downey Jr. will make a return as the armoured Avenger. **"When they signed us, they signed us for three. So that's it for the moment, but you never know."** However, wasn't The Avengers her third appearance as Pepper Potts?! It turns out that she actually did that as a favour (although it would obviously be more than a little naive to assume she wasn't paid for the privilege).

It would seem that when Gwenyth Paltrow first signed on to play Pepper Potts in *Iron Man*, she signed a three picture deal that was exhausted after appearing in;

- *Iron Man*, 2008
- *Iron Man 2*, 2010, and
- *Iron Man 3*, 2013

Her appearance in *Avengers Assemble* (2012) was done outside the terms of that contract.

However, it's probably worth noting that Gwenyth Paltrow has said she'd love to return to the role at some point. From that same article;

> As for whether or not Paltrow could ultimately be convinced to return as Pepper, she added: "I don't think they're going to make a Pepper Potts movie, so it depends on Iron Man and Robert. **I'd be open to more Pepper because I love working with Robert and it's a great franchise**. Most of the time I'm a full-time mother so it's nice for me to once in a while go and work on a big hit movie with great actors and then go back to North London and resume playdates and stuff like that! **I'm always happy when there's an opportunity to do it.**"

So, I think it's safe to assume that if Marvel Studios wanted to use Pepper Potts in another film, Gwenyth Paltrow would be happy to reprise the role.

As such, it seems that the reason for Pepper Potts' continued absence from the Marvel Cinematic Universe since 2013's *Iron Man 3* is simply because the films have not required the use of the character. In fact, it could be argued that her absence actually informs some of Tony's actions throughout *Captain America: Civil War*.

Comment: You always call it  Avengers Assemble, which sound bit weird to me, anyway +1

Comment: @AnkitSharma That's what it was released as in the UK! I can't help but call it that, because that's what it says on the front of my Blu Ray.

Comment: @AnkitSharma There's another movie called *The Avengers*, a British spy film that never got to be very well-known outside of the UK.  Marvel released *The Avengers* as *Avengers Assemble* in the UK to avoid confusion with that movie.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I know and even [answered it](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/2271/1190) long ago but to me it's always better to use more popular name.

Comment: @AnkitSharma So would an edit to avoid confusion be warranted? "Avengers Assemble" isn't even listed as an alternate name on IMDB which usually it is.

Comment: Avengers Assemble is also the title for the 2013 cartoon, complicating it even more.

Comment: @Insane It is listed under the "[Also Known As](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt#akas)" section of IMDb:

Answer (score 4):

I have heard a fictional theory to why she is absent in the movie..

> The [**theory**](http://www.inquisitr.com/3092782/pepper-potts-absent-from-captain-america-civil-war-is-gwyneth-paltrow-done-with-marvel/) states that Miss Pepper Potts grew tired of Tony lying to her. Apparently, Tony swore in **Iron Man 3** that he was never going to make any Iron Man/Mark costumes and Artificial Intelligence systems (**A.I's**) again, a promise which was broken when Tony created Ultron and Vision in **Avengers: Age of Ultron** Movie. Therefore, they are currently separated, and that's why she is not in Civil War.

However, there is speculation that she will appear in future Marvel Cinematic Universe films.

Comment: Is that actually a quote, or is it your own words? If it's your summary, it doesn't need to be in a quote block. The reference is good, though.